# Monitor Screen For a Parental Control App

Tags: android, kotlin, screenshot, screen-recording, parental-control

I am looking for a solution for a problem which is, I wan to monitor a phone screen for my parental control application. This application is based on detecting Toxic/18+ material on child's screen. It always notify parent whenever this type of toxicity is detected.

So how can i implement this app so that it can monitor Phone's screen

Thanks in advance!